# how to prevent horizontal scrolling in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile in which I seperated the page content into three div's horizontally, that is each div is an page. I used this logic for loading the page with animation using jquery mobile `load()` method.

The problem is that I can able to see the page(first div) in which I can scroll, So that it is showing the second page(second div) which I dont want to see.

**JS Code:**

```
$(document).on("touchmove","#homePageContent",false);
```

The above code prevents the screen scrolling horizontally and vertically but I want to prevent only horizontall scrolling.

`css overflow-x:hidden` is also not working.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle?